# Most game-consistent way to price creating magic weapons and armor from spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, pricing

Magic weapons and armor are one of the bases of the game. While there are many wonderful properties that are already available, sometimes there is a particular spell effect that you simply must have.
For example I will be playing a gestalt game soon where I am building a druid zen archer monk where I plan on using wild shape and a bow. The item [polymorphic pouch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/polymorphic-pouch/) has a much-desired feature, it doesn't meld when you polymorph.

As a bonus under the [polymorph](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation) rules

> If your new form does not cause your equipment to meld into your form, the equipment resizes to match your new size.

Originally I was going to add the effect to the weapon as if I was making a wondrous item as per the [standard table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#Table-Estimating-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values). While talking with a friend about it they instead priced it as another weapon property such as keen, flaming, shocking burst and thus expressed it as a +x bonus. I have to admit that this approach had not occurred to me, and thinking on it makes far more sense than the method I had planned on using.

Now there is an armor property called [wild](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/wild/) that serves a similar effect in that it lets you benefit from something that's melded with you. Using the weapon would be different, but similar.

Which approach to pricing spells onto magic weapons and armor gives more consistency with the game's overall pricing?

Comment: Define "Better."

Comment: @GMJoe From the rules point of view, since pretty much all weapon and armor properties are based on the bonus system, it makes sense that when adding new abilities to also use that system, instead of the more generic magic item rules that seem more based on the other magic items

Comment: No, I mean, what are your criteria for determining which system of pricing is "better?" Do you want weapons to be cheaper? More expensive? Do you want the prices to match those given in published products? Do you want them to incentivise certain designs of items and disincentivise others? Do you want to hew close to designer intent, insofar as designer intent can be known? When you say you want to know which method is "better," we can't answer usefully unless you tell us "better for what, and whom?"

Comment: @GMJoe I guess the best answer would be the designers intent. While I do some crazy things, I do try to stay within the rules as best I can. So I was the best way to price something thats not cheaper or more expensive but fits the current examples, much like my friend had pointed out.

Comment: Is there a way to phrase the question simply and clearly? Like *How much should a magic weapon special ability cost—in either magic +s or gp—that prevents the weapon from melding when its wielder is subject to a polymorph effect that causes him to assume the form of  an animal, dragon, elemental, magical beast, plant, or vermin?* only, y'know, simpler and clearer? Or is there more to this question than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Adding New Abilities](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/#TOC-Adding-New-Abilities), to add to an existing magic item the effects of a *polymorphic pouch*—an already slotless item—costs only 5,000 gp—, that is, the price of the of *polymorphic pouch*.

Precisely what such an effect *does* when applied to an existing magic bow is up to the GM, but this GM would allow a *+1 polymorphic bow* to remain unmelded when the owner changes forms *and* allow the bow's wielder to take a free purely mental action to retrieve one of the 100 arrows that's stored in the *bow*'s extradimensional space. (This saves the buyer from having to buy a second *polymorphic pouch* effect for his quiver!) In addition, because the GM's essentially more than halved the extradimensional space's capacity (the GM thinking 100 arrows more elegant than the 266 arrows a *pouch* could normally contain) *and* limited the extradimensional space to only arrows *but* allowed the wielder to retrieve an arrow stored in the space as a free action rather than as move action that provokes an attack of opportunity, the GM would likely reduce the price of adding the *pouch*'s effect to a magic bow by 10% to 4,500 gp, making that function, for example, less versatile but with more raw arrow storage than the 1,800 gp [*efficient quiver*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/efficient-quiver/).

#### "But how do I determine if a magic weapon special ability should be an enhancement-bonus equivalent (i.e. a *magic plus*) or a flat cost?"

If you're a player, you pitch the original item to the GM, and the GM will set the price. If you're the GM, you set the price by comparing the proposed original item to existing items.

More specifically, so far as I'm aware, there's no magical-enhancement-bonus-equivalent-to-flat-gp-value conversion in *Pathfinder*, but its antecedent *D&D 3.5e* provides a very basic guideline over the course of the 1st-level infusion *personal weapon augmentation* [trans] (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 117), the 4th-level infusion *weapon augmentation* [trans] (*ibid.*), and the 6th-level infusion *greater weapon augmentation* [trans] (*ibid.*). The first infusion allows an artificer to add to a weapon a weapon special ability "whose market price is equivalent to a +1 bonus or up to 10,000 gp," the second up to +3 or up to 70,000 gp, and the third up to +5 or up to 200,000 gp. (In either game, the referee must still adjudicate the gp equivalents to +2s and +4s!)

(By the way, armor and shields are similar except they're 1st-level, 3rd-level, and 5th-level infusions (e.g. *lesser armor enhancement* [trans] (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 109) *et al.*) and the flat gp value is *half* that of the equivalent magic weapon.)

Using the *weapon augmention* infusions as guidelines, the *Pathfinder* GM may rule that a *polymorphic pouch* effect applied to a magic bow is, instead, a weapon special ability worth a +1 enhancement bonus.

Comment: Im creating another magic item that will create arrows as needed at the correct size of my form, but as a worn item that I need access to Ill also have to give it this polymorphic process.
I did not know about the forgotten realms rules, thanks for pointing those out to me

Comment: @Fering (Honestly, I think the best solution is, before assuming a different form, *dropping the bow* then, after the new form's assumed, *recovering* the bow. While that may cost precious actions *in combat*, the duration of wild shape makes assuming a new form and *staying in it all day long* a strong possibility. This has the advantage of being *both* free *and* without controversy! Just sayin'.)

Answer (score -1):

Given that you want to add this quality to a weapon you should use pricing based on the +x system in conjunction with the craft magical arms and armor feat as its intended use.

If you just want the bow to not meld with you when you wild shape I would argue its a +1 bonus. If you want the weapon to actually be usable in your new form (bears are known for their hugs not their marksmanship) I would say that the cost should be equivalent to the transformative weapon quality. I'm not able to look that up at the time of writing this. The ammunition would also need to receive this enchantment as well.

Of course if you just don't want it to meld you could just drop the equipment before you transform so it doesn't meld.☺